# How to load dynamic url as static with Zeit.co for nextjs app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a nextjs app that where I have this on my server.js:

```
 server.get('/recipes/:urlId', (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = '/recipe'
      const queryParams = { urlId: req.params.urlId }
      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
    })
```

So basically whenever I try to reach /recipes/{something} it renders the page with queryParams. 
This is used later to call an api that will reach for the actual recipe information before displaying it back to the user.

If the user navigate from within the application, it works fine and I can pass the parameters properly and everything works ok.

But if I get the url and paste it directly on the url, I get a 404 instead of the recipe.

Running locally it works fine, but when I deploy it to Zeit I get this issue.
Is there something I need to configure there? Does it use the server.js I have set on my app locally or it uses something else?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the url makes the server to search for the folder recipe and to search for the folder which you have passed the `urlId`.

There are two ways you can do this.

1) So you have to tell the server that do not look for the folder just redirect the url for any url to index.html page

Or

2) You can use the hash strategy to make the url have # location path

Check the other solution here [Router not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually).

Or You can add the htaccess file for the server side changes may not be possible